# How to use Spring applicationContext to retrieve a message from messageSource?

Tags: java, spring

here is my WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml :

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/resources/messages"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="configurationService" class="com.services.ConfigurationService"/>
<bean id="companyService" class="com.services.CompanyService"/>
<bean id="messageService" class="com.services.MessageService"/>
```

It is working perfectly in jsps (spring:message). The problem is I can not retrieve the messages in my `MessageService`. I've tried two different approaches : the first one (see the code below) is to make my `MessageService` "aware" of the context, by implementing `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware`. The context is loaded by Spring during initialization, but when I try to find the bean under name "messageResource", the `applicationContext.getBean("messageSource")` returns `null`.

```
package com.services;

import java.util.Locale;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;

public class MessageService implements ApplicationContextAware{

/** MessageService Instance */
private static MessageService instance = null;

/** Spring Message source*/
private ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

/** Application context */
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

/** Return MessageService instance */
public final static MessageService getInstance()
{
    if (MessageService.instance==null)
    {
        synchronized(MessageService.class)
        {
            if (MessageService.instance==null)
                MessageService.instance = new MessageService();

        }
    }
    return instance;
}


/**  Return a message */    
public String getMessage(String messageId)
{
    messageSource = (ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource)applicationContext.getBean("messageSource");
    Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
    return messageSource.getMessage(messageId,null, locale);
}

@Override
@Autowired
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext; 

}
}
```

The second approach was to load the context in my `MessageService` using `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`. the `applicationContext.getBean("messageSource")` doesn't return `null` anymore, but `messageSource.getMessage(messageId,null, locale)` can't find any message (`NoSuchMessageException`). The messages of course are present in my .properties

Both problems look like context problems, but I can't figure out to use the same .properties files in both .jsp and java classes. Plus, I would like to have the messages loaded once in the application during initialization, and not having to load them every time I need them in a class. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured that out by moving my .properties in a directory in the classpath. For those who would be interested :

```
<bean id="messageSource"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="resources/language/messages"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageService" class="com.services.MessageService" factory-method="getInstance"/>
```

MessageService

```
package com.services;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;

public class MessageService implements ApplicationContextAware{

/** MessageService Instance */
private static MessageService instance = null;

/** Spring Message source*/
private ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

/** Application context */
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

/** Return MessageService instance */
public final static MessageService getInstance()
{
    if (MessageService.instance==null)
    {
        synchronized(MessageService.class)
        {
            if (MessageService.instance==null)
                MessageService.instance = new MessageService();

        }
    }
    return instance;
}


/**  Return a message */    
public String getMessage(String messageId)
{
    messageSource = (ResourceBundleMessageSource) applicationContext.getBean("messageSource");
    Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
    return messageSource.getMessage(messageId,null, locale);
}


@Override
@Autowired
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext; 

}
}
```

Note :this code doesn't work with
`ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`. 
The way it tries to find the resources doesn't seem to be the way than `ResourceBundleMessageSource`.

Comment: is it mandatory to mention `id="messageSource"` in `<bean id="messageSource"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">` ? or will it work fine without giving it ?